# error "Finder got an error: mkdir: /file: Read-only file system" number 1

Tags: applescript

I have an AppleScript I've been using for a long time, and it works great. It pulls down a file from a URL, then pushes it up to a folder on our server. We got a new server and now the script doesn't work anymore. The old server was a Server 2016 Box. The new server is virtualized, running Server 2022 Standard. Here is the script:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        activate
        tell application "System Events" to tell process "Google Chrome" to open location "http://boonegraphics.myprintdesk.net/DSF/PreviewPdf.ashx?1vIGcx4dg0fGKdUPOijyz3th135nK6adXcXoquct9+GghoEmtIsfjU0PAw2gKZT5+ikF0gJTgDShYOIH2pxK7eZOrBnC4UaAs80fvactWGLNSRnxGGWb4HcqOkGF7u4tjwD8bwz1eT0TxWrzQt6m90Y4IbC0D/KSL9TFVyZz9H/XIUmA49CnHQ=="
    end tell
    delay 3
    
    --Move file to customer supplied folder of applicable job then delete downloaded file from this computer
    tell application "Finder"
        set myFolder to ("Macintosh HD:Users:scriptrunner2021:Downloads:")
        set targetFolder to ("file://bggol-vesko01.boone.local/Jobs_23/90528_FiveCitiesFireAuthority/Customer Supplied/") & "PartNum1"

        do shell script "mkdir -p " & quoted form of POSIX path of targetFolder

        set finalFolder to ("file://bggol-vesko01.boone.local/Jobs_23/90528_FiveCitiesFireAuthority/Customer Supplied/PartNum1" as POSIX file)
        delay 5.0

        set myFile to get every item of (entire contents of folder myFolder)
        move myFile to finalFolder with replacing
        set myFile to delete every item of (entire contents of folder myFolder)
    end tell
end tell
```

It downloads the file without any issue but when it trys to write the 'PartNum1' Directory to the server I get an error:

```
error "Finder got an error: mkdir: /file: Read-only file system" number 1
```

It seems to hangup on this line of the script:

```
do shell script "mkdir -p " & quoted form of POSIX path of targetFolder
```

Comment: In trying to diagnose it, what have you tried? What happened instead of it working? My first thought was to fire up Terminal and run `mkdir -p "file://bggol-vesko01.boone.local/Jobs_23/90528_FiveCitiesFireAuthority/Customer Supplied/PartNum1"`

Comment: Thanks for asking.  I have triple checked that I have permissions.  I have tried changing file to sbm, cifs. even added , var 2.1 to the end of the string.

Comment: The `targetFolder` doesn’t look right (is that supposed to be an URL?) - the destination appears to be defaulting to the root system folder, which is read-only.

Comment: I think the @red_menace is right about the targetFolder. `posix path` is intended for extracting from HFS type paths, not a file URL (and shouldn't there be three `///` after 'file'? I get a peculiar looking result when I run `POSIX path of targetFolder`. I think it's actually attempting to access the folder `file` inside the root — which probably doesn't exist and isn't where your files are anyway.

Comment: @Mockman is there a better way to write that '''targetFolder''' command?

Comment: The trick is that you must figure out how to specify something on the server. I don't have access to any servers to test out the syntax. What happens (in a separate script) if you `set xy to choose file` and select a file in that folder? Does it return a valid file reference and can you then coerce that to a posix path? Also… Apple suggests that when you Get Info a file and look under 'where', you will see the posix path. Perhaps you can use that? Alternatively (but you'll still need to figure out the reference) you could use an applescript command rather than mkdir to create the directory.

Comment: `file://bggol-vesko01.boone.local` makes no sense. A file system URL starts with `file:///`, the third slash is the root directory, and it represents an URL, not a path. However `mkdir` expects a path without the `file://` scheme. And `POSIX path of targetFolder` makes no sense either because it's already slash separated.

Comment: Problem solved.  In the earlier version of the software we are running on this server, the software would pass file locations off as "Volumes/Jobs_23/90528_FiveCitiesFireAuthority/Customer Supplied/PartNum1".

With this new version, it now passes the locations as "file://bggol-vesko01.boone.local/Jobs_23/90528_FiveCitiesFireAuthority/Customer Supplied/PartNum1"

I wrote a quick script to change "file://bggol-vesko01.boone.local/" to "/Volumes/"  and now my apple scripts work again.

Thank you all for the feedback, it pointed me in the right direction and ultimately the solution.